# Issue with using JSTL tag library with Tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

This might sound like a strange problem but I'm not being able to use the jstl tag library in my J2EE application running on Tomcat server. This same web application is running perfectly fine on GlassFish server but when I created another project and copied `signup.jsp` which used jstl tags then I'm getting error. My `PageController` code is,

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("ai");
        try {

            request.getRequestDispatcher("pages/signup.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } finally {            
            out.println("af");
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Here only "af" is printed and not "ai". Now if I remove jstl code from `signup.jsp` then the code works well. Now my question is do I have to add any additional files to make jstl files to work in tomcat server?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by _if I remove jstl code_ code ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi It means when I remove the lines that used JSTL code then my application works fine

Comment: which lines are those ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for being late to post an answer to this question.

Glassfish comes with all the libraries required to run the JSTL tags but for Apache you need to download those libraries. I found [**this link**](https://jstl.java.net/download.html) on the internet from which you can download all the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc of [`RequestDispatcher#forward(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) states

> `forward` should be called before the response has been committed to the
>   client (before response body output has been flushed). If the response
>   already has been committed, this method throws an
>   IllegalStateException. **Uncommitted output in the response buffer is
>   automatically cleared before the forward.**

It makes sense therefore that

```
out.println("ai");
```

isn't printed. But there doesn't seem to be any relation with tag libraries. Also, the specification doesn't say anything about tag library involvement in the `RequestDispatcher`, so it might just be a vendor specific behavior.